# Jquery should run only when the check box is checked in

Tags: jquery

`enter code here`My requirement is i am having the images and a check box on a page.Now when the check box is checked in and when i place my mouse hover the image the jquery should run.

When the check box is checked out and the mouse hover is on the image the jquery should not run....

my code is like this..

```
$(document).ready(
 function()
    {
     $("#box img").click(
            function()
                {

                    var sr=$(this).attr("src");                    
                    //alert(sr);
                    $("#box2 img").fadeOut("slow",function(){
                    $("#box2").html("<img src='"+sr+"' style='opacity:0.30'/>");
                    $("#box2 img").fadeTo("slow",1);
                    });


                }
        );
        $("#box img").hover(
            function()
            {
                $(this).css({'z-index' : '10','border':'4px solid white'});
                $(this).animate({
                marginTop: '-110px',
            marginLeft: '-110px',
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%',
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px'        
            },200);
            },
```

Now i need to run this functions only when the check box is checked in...

Comment: Need more information. What do you mean when you state you want the jquery to run? Do you have some code we could see to better understand what you mean?

Comment: i just added the code in the question so could you just help me out..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to execute some javascript code (with jquery) in particular cases only, right?

so suppose you have checkbox with `id="check"` and image with `id="pix"`

you have to put this in your document ready part:

```
$('#pix').mouseover(function(){
  if($('#check').is(':checked')){
    //your code is here or function call
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think you want is:

```
$('#image').hover(function () {
if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    //Your code to do what ever you want on entry
}
}, function () {
if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    //Your code to do what ever you want on exit
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#image_1').mouseover(function() {
  if ($('#checkbox_1').is(':checked').length == 1)
  {
     // do stuff
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk_1" name="chkbox[]" value="" />
<img id="img_1" src="some_image.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img[id^='img_']").mouseover(function() {
      var id = $(this).split("_")[1];
      if($("input[id='chk_"+id+"']").is(":checked")) {
          //run something
      }
  });
});
</script>
```